# Plutus V2 Primitives

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

Does any have (or has anyone found) a simple summary of Plutus V2 Primitives?  They made the short list of big changes in the Vasil fork announcement, so they seem important.  Other than just reading haddock after searching for Plutus.V2, is there a resource for understanding and using the new stuff?

Might be a Lars Office Hours kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Michele said, maybe the following repo helps understand the new cips [(1)](https://github.com/perturbing/vasil-tests/). It has some nice examples on how to use the new functionalities.

Note however that we are currently in the transition of a new cost model on the testnet, we have to wait for epoch 216 I think). After that update Plutus V2 script will become available.

Comment: Great repo with enough information to lead me where I want to go.  Thanks @fermat.

Comment: If you try to compile the code examples, do not forget to use the next node branch of the plutus-app repository. The main branch is not ready yet for plutusV2, I think.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose, I found useful the [source code itself](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/tree/master/plutus-ledger-api/src/PlutusLedgerApi/V2)

in particular, I think a good starting point would be [the `Plutus.V2` version of `TxInfo`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/b39a526e983cb931d0cc49b7d073d6d43abd22b5/plutus-ledger-api/src/PlutusLedgerApi/V2/Contexts.hs#L76)

other than the new information available there should not be any difference in writing the smart contracts.